# Info not updated in database

Tags: php, mysql

once again it is me. I'll promise after this one I am done bothering you for a while!:)

I have this rating system, which would allow user to rate an article. It is somewhat working, but the thing is that it doesn't update the data in the database and I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated. :)

```
// Connects to your Database 
 mysql_connect("URL", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error()); 


     //Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating  
 if(isset($_submit['voted'])) { 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total= total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id"); 

        Echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
        } 



 //Puts SQL Data into an array
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vote") or die(mysql_error()); 

 //Now we loop through all the data 
 while($ratings = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 //This outputs the sites name 
 Echo "Name: " .$ratings['name']."<br>"; 

 //This calculates the sites ranking and then outputs it - rounded to 1 decimal 
 $current = $ratings['total'] / $ratings['votes']; 
 Echo "Current Rating: " . round($current, 1) . "<br>"; 




 //This creates 5 links to vote a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 rating for each particular item 
 Echo "Rank Me: "; 
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings['id'].">1</a> | "; //The HREF was ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." before
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings['id'].">2</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=3&id=".$ratings['id'].">3</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=4&id=".$ratings['id'].">4</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=5&id=".$ratings['id'].">5</a><p>"; 
 } 


 ?>
```

Thanks guys!: )

Comment: Default username & password for mysql in local host is root.

Comment: what is `total` in `total+$voted,` ?

Comment: Try changing `$_submit['voted']` to `$_POST['voted']`

Comment: check your `$id` if it exist or its there.

Comment: Tried both $_submit and $_POST. The id's are there in the database.

Comment: no , i mean try echo `$id` if there is or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relace this line

```
if(isset($_submit['voted'])) { 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total= total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id"); 

       echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
        }
```

With this

```
if(isset($_POST['voted'])) { 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total= total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id"); 

        echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
        }
```

Comment: Where you declare $id variable?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. Doesn't it pull the id from the database? I have the table there with variable ID, name, total, votes.

Comment: try echo your query like this $query= "UPDATE vote SET total= total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id"; echo $query; exit;

Comment: First echo this query and then you realize your mistake take it easy. For debugging you must use echo $variable and for array you must use print_r($variable);

Comment: I gave plus 1 to the answer now even tho I didn't give +1 to the comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

there is **No $_SUBMIT** superglobal variable in php

use `$_POST` or  `$_GET`

[Read here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals.asp)

if you still have problem check for errors using `mysql_error()`

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total= total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id") 
or  die(mysql_error());
```

or echo your query and run it in your local database.

and then share your error with us.

*Dont use mysql_* as they are depracated.*

Comment: Hey man! Tried it and now it gives me this: Notice: Undefined variable: voted in /home/kall0467/public_html/svale_rejser/vote.php on line 11 Notice: Undefined variable: id in /home/kall0467/public_html/svale_rejser/vote.php on line 11 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' votes = votes+1 WHERE id =' at line 1

Comment: @user2983295 that means your problem is solved . :) now check $id from where its coming and why it is empty.

Comment: I am really new to databases and PHP so sorry for my stupidity, but I have the variable id and variable voted in the database. Do I have to define them in the code as well somewhere?

Comment: ya in order to use the variables in the server side,they should be sent to the server side so what i mean is $id should be available to server while processing.are you taking id from any input type,any form?share your html

Comment: Nope. I think I am missing the HTML part. I followed this tutorial actually and edited it a little bit (removed the cookies thing and changed the titles and href): http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/rating_script.htm

Comment: @user2983295 never do this.if you want  to learn something start from scratch.first learn html and when you are good enough with html then move to scripting language.html form will play a great role so start learning .than you will find these things easy. :)

Comment: well yea, you have your point tho. I'm decent with html and wanted to try php because it is our school assignment atm. they ask us to use magic php which is our teacher's framework based on php, but it sucks a lot.. so i thought I'll thought I'll go with the regular php. I can do simple functions in PHP, but this one is a pain in the ass. Thanks for the help, I wont give up tho! :)

Comment: @user2983295 never give up :) u know html so try to learn more about form and its attribute like action and method attribute.if you find any difficulty feel free to ask me. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$_GET`

```
     //Then we update the voting information by adding 1 to the total votes and adding their vote (1,2,3,etc) to the total rating  
 if(isset($_GET['voted'])) { 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total= total+$_GET['voted'], votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $_GET['id']"); 

        Echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First: use `$_GET['voted']` instead of `$_submit['voted']`.

In addition the links you built are wrong. Change

```
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings['id'].">1</a> | "; //The HREF was ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." before
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings['id'].">2</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=3&id=".$ratings['id'].">3</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=4&id=".$ratings['id'].">4</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href='index.php?site=kumu'?mode=vote&voted=5&id=".$ratings['id'].">5</a><p>";
```

to

```
 Echo "<a href=index.php?site=kumu&mode=vote&voted=1&id=".$ratings['id'].">1</a> | "; //The HREF was ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']." before
 Echo "<a href=index.php?site=kumu&mode=vote&voted=2&id=".$ratings['id'].">2</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=index.php?site=kumu&mode=vote&voted=3&id=".$ratings['id'].">3</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=index.php?site=kumu&mode=vote&voted=4&id=".$ratings['id'].">4</a> | "; 
 Echo "<a href=index.php?site=kumu&mode=vote&voted=5&id=".$ratings['id'].">5</a><p>";
```

**UPDATE**

Replace the statement:

```
 if(isset($_submit['voted'])) { 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total= total+$voted, votes = votes+1 WHERE id = $id"); 

        Echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
        }
```

With:

```
 if(isset($_GET['voted']) && is_numeric($_GET['voted'])) { 
 mysql_query ("UPDATE vote SET total= total+ " . $_GET['voted'] . ", votes = votes+1 WHERE id = " . $_GET['id']); 

        Echo "Your vote has been cast <p>"; 
        }
```

Of course, a better parameter validation and escaping is mandatory in order to prevent any SQLInjection.

Comment: When I changed it then it says this: Notice: Undefined variable: voted in /home/kall0467/public_html/svale_rejser/vote.php on line 11 Notice: Undefined variable: id in /home/kall0467/public_html/svale_rejser/vote.php on line 11 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' votes = votes+1 WHERE id =' at line 1

Comment: I got it fixed earlier and the site is fully functional now! Thanks for all the help :) Merry Christmas